# Checkbox values getting without page loading using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem getting checkbox value in the following code(without page loading).
If I click on checkboxes the values can be passed through the array variable `check`. But whenever I click checkbox I get `" Array ( [0] => undefined )".`

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<script src="create_ajax_object.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function display() {
    var ajax = create_ajax_object();
    if (ajax) {
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.open("POST", "fetchdata.php", true);
        var check = new Array();
        var "check[]=" + encodeURIComponent(document.myForm.user.value);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajax.send(check[]);
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesnt support AJAX!");
    }
} </script>
<br>
<form name='myForm'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="First" onclick="display();">1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Second" onclick="display();">2
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Third" onclick="display();">3
    <br>
</form>

</html>
```

fetchdata.php

```
<?php
$no=array($_POST['check']);
foreach($no as $n)
{
  print_r($n);
}   
?>
```

Comment: Fix your syntax error: `var "check[]=" + ...` is not a valid statement, you need a variable name and assignment operator after `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `document.myForm.user` is array of checkbox objects, you have to iterate over it and check `checked` property of each element.

Comment: Hi Marek iam little new to programming..will you please explain with coding?

Comment: It would be better if you use some js library. For example with jQuery it would be as simple as $.post('fetchdata.php', $('form[name="myForm"]').serialize(), function(data) { $('#target').html(data); });

Comment: Hi Barmer,marek still there is no improvement ... :( if i use one checkbox this method works)...but in the case of multiple check box there is no change.. :( please help me

Comment: Now the code        var check=new Array();                         var "check="+encodeURIComponent(document.myForm.user[i].value);
 for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++)
   {
   ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   ajax.send(check);
            }                but there is no change ...

Comment: You have to change the checkbox name to check[]. All of them.

Comment: <form name='myForm'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="First" onclick="display();">1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Second" onclick="display();">2
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Third" onclick="display();">3

Comment: ya change it..But not displays anything...         var check=new Array(); 
  for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++) 
  { 
  var "check="+encodeURIComponent(document.myForm.user[i].value); 
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
  ajax.send(check[i]); 
  }

Comment: You should really use jQuery, your js skills are not up to the task.